# How to use pagination with button control

Tags: ios, objective-c

[image: just like this image]Hello i want to use pagination in my app with button control and compatible with every acreen of iphone. I applied pagination with scrollview but having problem in getting view by button click. Any suggestions? The idea is same as we see in whatsapp.

Comment: do you want something like top fixed tabbar ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change content offset on button click. for example for second page,

```
CGPoint newOffset = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width, 0);
[self.standardScrollView setContentOffset:newOffset animated:YES];

//for third page
 CGPoint newOffset = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width*2, 0);
[self.standardScrollView setContentOffset:newOffset animated:YES];
```

vise versa for goes to back.
Hope this will help :)

Comment: you're welcome... :) if you feel this is helpful then upvote the answer :)